# Error running Typescript task in Visual Studio Code due to spaces in "Visual Studio Code"

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm getting the following error and believe I know why (the spaces in "Visual Studio Code" in the path), but I'm not sure where/how to fix it. It seems quotes around "Visual Studio Code" in the path would do the trick.  Anyone else seen this before?

> Executing task: c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio Code\leasemileage\node_modules.bin\tsc.cmd -p "c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio Code\leasemileage\tsconfig.json" <

c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual : The term 'c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio Code\leasemileage\node_module ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Comment: Do you have typescript in your PATH? `tsc -v` command should give you your global typescript version.

Comment: tsc -v shows 2.4.1, package.json was ~2.3.3 (which I changed to ~2.4.1), windows environment path includes npm, but shows no typescript version number.

Comment: Just go to that folder ( `leasemileage` ) with the help of `cd` command. And then run `tsc`.

Comment: I am seeing the same error.  Having seen something similar before, I'm thinking that the spaces in "Visual Studio Code" are causing Powershell to get confused.  Perhaps I should try GitBash?  Thanks, BTW, for your time, Alex!

Comment: Are you using just `tsc` - only 3 letter command?

Comment: Error: > Executing task: c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio Code\leasemileage\node_modules\.bin\tsc.cmd -p "c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio Code\leasemileage\tsconfig.json" <

c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual : The term 'c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ c:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio Code\leasemileage\node_module ...

Comment: Yes, just "tsc" in the "leasemileage" subdir and received the error above.

Comment: Does something stops you from moving the project then?

Comment: For me PowerShell and bash both working for folders with spaces.